# Make my program the "Choose Default Program" when opening a file

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I'm making a music player. And what I basically want to know is how to make your program open a file which was clicked by the user in explorer.

For instance:

I've set my music player to the deafult program for opening .mp3's.
And when I double click a .mp3 file in my music folder, I want my program to open and start playing that song.

But how does that work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a C# Application work as the default program for certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789319/how-to-make-a-c-sharp-application-work-as-the-default-program-for-certain-files)

Answer (score 5):

This is handled via the registry.  You can see details of the (many) registry keys and values required to [properly setup a file association here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9093617/65358).

That being said, the best way to handle this is typically via your installation.  Windows Installer supports the [RegisterExtensionInfo extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371156%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which will properly setup the registry for you during your program's installation.