# Files can not be opened directly by an application in which they were created

Tags: java, windows, path

I have installed a Java Application[which creates slides presentations like powerpoint] on my computer. It runs successfully from start menu. But when I Open the file created in that application, it does not opens, application does not launches. Somehow those files can't find the path to that application. does anyone have any idea what possibly could be the issue? I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses file associations to know which application can handle which file type.

These associations aren't created by magic; either an installer creates them or you need to create them manually. When you right-click the file and select "Open", Windows should ask you which application to use. Select your Java app and it might work.

"Might" since some applications don't accept command line arguments. That means Windows can't tell the app which file to open. If that's the case, then you need to launch your app manually and then open the file from within the app.

Related:

- [Add a new file association in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093481/add-a-new-file-association-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for you response :) This I am already doing, right click the file, open with -> then I guide it to the exe of my Application. select/apply and click ok, but application is still not able to open it. what i have noticed is that application process starts in task manager and exits after 1 or 2 seconds. Second option that you told is already working, I can open file from file menu when application is running. Link that you mention is helpful, I have made another file association using regedit, that is functional for these kind of files, but still application does not loads file.

Comment: In that case, try to run the application from the command line and pass the file to open as argument. If you see an error, let us know the exact error message.

Comment: It was running only in case that we provide complete path of application and complete path of file as arguments. Now that issue is resolved. Actually something went wrong during the build of application. And btw setting file association in registry editor manually is a good solution and application works fine with files later on. Thank you very much for your help.