# How to get c++ program to execute in response to file opening?

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I wrote a c++ program that can save its internal state to the disk in a file of a custom type. How can I get windows to run my program upon a file of this type being double clicked? Is there a method of passing arguments to main() so the program knows what file was selected?

Comment: This should be moved to SuperUser I believe? It's a question about Windows default programs, not programming.

Comment: This [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093481/add-a-new-file-association-in-windows-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) might help

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: It's two questions in one. The second part ("method of passing arguments to main()) is clearly about programming.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "Run with..." from the Windows explorer context menu, you can select your application binary.

Windows will supply the absolute file path as the first argument to your application.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc < 2)
    std::cout << "No argument" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "Filename is " << argv[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Why 2 arguments? Because arguments always start in argv[1]. argv[0] usually contains the path to your application binary.

If you call "d:\MyApp.exe c:\MyImage.bmp" then

```
argc == 2
argv[0] == "d:\MyApp.exe"
argv[1] == "c:\MyImage.bmp"
```

Comment: *"Because argv[0] always contains the path to your application binary."* - This is not true. Passing the pathname to the executable image as the first command line argument is a *convention*, not a strict rule. If you read the documentation for [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx), you will see, that there are no restrictions as to what you can pass as the first command line argument.